# Painted faces of n×n×n cube

Tags: graphics3d, geometry

[image]

Given a 3×3×3 cube made of 27 unit blocks. If the cube is painted, then each of the blocks has 3 of its faces painted, a given block may have 0, 1, 2 , or 3 of its faces painted. I want to mark different colors for them. I came up with the following way, it only works for n=3 and n=4, and coloring only the boundary is better than coloring the whole cube. Do you have a better way? Maybe the mesh based method will be useful.

```
n = 3;
pts = Tuples[Range[0, n - 1], 3];
pts1 = Tuples[{0, n - 1}, 3];
pts2 = Position[CrossMatrix[All, n {1, 1, 1}], 1] - 1;
pts3 = Complement[pts, pts1, pts2];
Graphics3D[{
  Red, Translate[Cuboid[], pts1],
  Blue, Translate[Cuboid[], pts2],
  Green, Translate[Cuboid[], pts3]
  }]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Updated

- We use `GridGraph` to get the relations of the connect.
- By using such connect relation, we can collect which surfaces of the cuboids should be colorize.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 5;
g = Graph3D[GridGraph[{n, n, n}], 
   VertexCoordinates -> Tuples[Range[n], 3]];
coords = AssociationThread[VertexList[g] -> GraphEmbedding[g]];
colors = {1 -> Blue, 2 -> Green, 3 -> Red, 0 -> Opacity[.5]};
index2normal = {1 -> {0, 0, -1}, 2 -> {0, -1, 0}, 3 -> {1, 0, 0}, 
   4 -> {0, 1, 0}, 5 -> {-1, 0, 0}, 6 -> {0, 0, 1}};
normal2index = Reverse[index2normal, {2}];
normal[i_] := # - (i /. coords) & /@ (AdjacencyList[g, i] /. coords);
draw[i_] := 
  Module[{indexs, coidexs, faces}, 
   indexs = normal[i] /. normal2index;
   coindexs = Complement[Range[6], indexs];
   faces = MeshPrimitives[Cuboid[(i /. coords)/.75], 2];
   {Length@coindexs /. colors, faces[[coindexs]], Opacity[.5], White, 
    faces[[indexs]]}];
Graphics3D[Table[draw[i], {i, VertexList[g]}], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

A starting point.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 8;
g = Graph3D[GridGraph[{n, n, n}], EdgeStyle -> Transparent];
vd = VertexDegree[g];
rules = {1 -> Magenta, 2 -> Green, 3 -> Red, 4 -> Green, 5 -> Blue, 
   6 -> Opacity[.5]};
vf2[pt_, name_, bd_] := {EdgeForm[Black], Cuboid[pt - bd, pt + bd]}
size = .5;
HighlightGraph[g, 
 Table[Style[VertexList[g][[i]], vd[[i]] /. rules], {i, 
   VertexCount[g]}], EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", 
 VertexShapeFunction -> vf2, VertexSize -> size, 
 VertexCoordinates -> Tuples[Range[n], 3]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
ClearAll[coloredCuboids];

coloredCuboids[m_] :=
 Map[{Switch[Count[#, 1 | m], 3, Red, 2, Green, _, Blue], Cuboid @ #} & ] @ 
 Tuples[Range @ m, 3]

Multicolumn[Graphics3D[coloredCuboids[#], 
    Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 150, PlotLabel -> #] & /@ Range[12],
  4, Appearance -> "Horizontal"]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice work!(+1) How do we color only the outside faces, just like the second row of the picture in the question?

Answer (score 3):

**Using `Array*` functions:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
cubesArray[n_Integer /; n <= 2] := Module[{res},
  If[n < 1, res = "\[Wolf]"];
  If[n == 1, res = {{{2}}}];
  If[n == 2 , res = {{{2, 2}, {2, 2}}, {{2, 2}, {2, 2}}}];
  res
  ]

cubesArray[n_Integer /; n > 2] := Module[{tmid, tupdn, res},
  tmid = ConstantArray[ConstantArray[3, {n, n}] //
     ReplacePart[#, {{1, 1} -> 1, {1, n} -> 1, {n, 1} -> 1, {n, n} -> 
         1}] &, n - 2];
  tupdn = 
   ArrayPad[ConstantArray[3, {n - 2, n - 2}], 1, 1] // 
    ReplacePart[#, {{1, 1} -> 2, {1, n} -> 2, {n, 1} -> 2, {n, n} -> 
        2}] &;
  res = Join[{tupdn}, tmid, {tupdn}] 
  ]
```

---

*Usage*:

```
ArrayPlot3D[cubesArray[#]
     , ColorRules -> {1 -> Green, 2 -> Red, 3 -> Blue}
     , Boxed -> False
     , PlotLabel -> #
     ] & /@ Range[1, 11] //
  Partition[#, UpTo[4]] & // GraphicsGrid[#, ImageSize -> 600] &
```

[image]

---

*Explanations:*

Essentially it is a stack up of 2D matrices in 3D. For example,

```
cubesArray[4] // Map[MatrixForm]
```

[image]

Since the `cubesArray` is being built up from the inside out, the first two cases are conveniently added using custom definitions above.

For `n>2`, there is an array `tmid` of `n-2` slices (matrices) which are `Blue` colored  initially. `Green` corners are added to each using `ReplacePart`.

The top and bottom (or more correctly called front and back) slices called `tupdn` start out with a blue core which is `n-2` x `n-2`. This is `ArrayPad`ed with `Green` sides, and  then the `Red` corners are added using `ReplacePart`.

Subsequently, the 3D matrix is put together using the `Join` command.